# Outputting Object to File

Tags: java, serialization

I am looking for a way to output an instantiated class, an Object to a file. I have tried using FileStream and it doesn't seem to be working. After researching, it seems as though i need to use a technique called "serialization". I'm absolutely lost on this topic. Would someone please debug this code for me? I have a hunch that the problem is occurring because I am trying to serialize an abstract class within a normal class. The abstract class is java.util.Calendar.

```
class CalendarL implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    java.util.Calendar calendar;

    CalendarL (int date, int month, int year){
        calendar.set (Calendar.DATE, date);
calendar.set (Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.set (Calendar.YEAR, year);
    }
}

class IO {
    protected CalendarL reader() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream data = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
        ObjectInputStream dataObject = new ObjectInputStream(data);

        CalendarL calendar = (CalendarL)dataObject.readObject();

        dataObject.close();
        data.close();

        return calendar;
    }


    protected void output(CalendarL calendar) throws IOException, WriteAbortedException, NotSerializableException {
        new FileOutputStream("data.dat").close();

        FileOutputStream data = new FileOutputStream("data.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream dataObject = new ObjectOutputStream(data);

        dataObject.writeObject(calendar);
        dataObject.close();
        data.close();
   }
```

}

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: hotelres.ClientL
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the error.

Comment: IMO, you should store the timestamp value as `long` or `java.util.Date` rather than `Calendar`.

Comment: @Genzer Many useful functions in java.util.Date were deprecated in a long time ago. We think alike. Date was my first choice.

I thought using a long would be more work than required as it would demand the creation of methods to compare dates when it is already existent in the Calendar class.

Comment: your code should work fine, except for the compile errors already mentioned in comments.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi I have added the parameters.

Comment: Is that the real code, and the real exception message?  'Cos that code looks like it *should* work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a hunch that the problem is occurring because I am trying to serialize an abstract class within a normal class. The abstract class is java.util.Calendar.

That hunch is not correct.  You serialize instances (not classes) and the class of an instance cannot be an abstract class.  Besides, the `Calendar` class *does* implement `Serializable` ... the javadoc says so.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Stephen. Turns out, I had an object within the Calendar. I had to implement Serializable in that class too.